# "sp_updatestats"

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server database size is around 10 GB, when I ran a `sp_updatestats` query with my selected database, then SQL Server query is fetching results quickly.

After a few days (2 or 3 days), stored procedures and queries are very slow again.

Please help me about this.

Comment: Create a job that run sp_updatestats and schedule it to run every night

Comment: it is the best way to ? or i need to do something else ?